# Optimal growth between variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization

I want to see what term of this function makes it grow the fastest and what term makes it grow the slowest.
How do I do that? From playing around with random values so far I suspect  that there are points in the plane where 1 term is dominant but after a while a new term takes the lead. The function is:
$$ f(a,b,c) = 10(5 \times a + b)(1+0.05 \times c) $$
The ranges for the variables are the following :
$$ 1 \leq a \leq 800 , \space  1 \leq b \leq 22500 , \space 1 \leq c \leq 80 $$

Comment: look at the partial derivatives

Comment: does this mean calculating  $$ max(\frac{\partial f(b_{max},c_{max})}{\partial a}, \frac{\partial f(a_{max},c_{max})}{\partial b}, \frac{\partial f(a_{max},b_{max})}{\partial c})  $$ to obtain the max value ?